# How do I close Firebase connection once data is loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In this class, I have a method fetchRestaurants that goes into Firebase using ObserveSingleEvent.The data is loaded onto the array and the table view cells are populated. My problem is that the Firebase connection does not close therefore every time I try to sort the tableview or even slide up or down the tableview it pulls from Firebase and causing the receiving data to increase significantly. What do y'all recommend? I've been at my desk for the past 6 hrs trying to close the connection my class is below:

```
//
//  HomeTableViewController.swift
//  Fresco
//
//  Created by Antonio Rodriguez on 12/31/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 FrescoInc. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

enum selectedScope: Int {
    case name = 0
    case rating = 1
    case price = 2
}


class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{

    //firebase refrences
    var restaurantArray = [Restaurant]()

    var dataBaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference! {
        return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Home"
        self.searchBarSetup()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "menuIcon") , style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(SSASideMenu.presentLeftMenuViewController))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setBackButtonBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "backButton"), for: .normal , barMetrics: .default)
       fetchRestaurants()
        tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "mainPageBackground"))
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
       // fetchRestaurants()
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    func fetchRestaurants(){
       dataBaseRef.child("AthensRestaurants/Restaurants").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var results = [Restaurant]()

            for res in snapshot.children{
                let res = Restaurant(snapshot: res as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                results.append(res)
        }

            self.restaurantArray = results.sorted(by: { (u1, u2) -> Bool in
                u1.name < u2.name
            })
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.dataBaseRef.removeAllObservers()

    }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return restaurantArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "restaurantsCell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantsTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...

        cell.configureCell(res: restaurantArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        return cell
    }

    //transfers data to new page
    func showRestaurantViewControllerWith(_ res: Restaurant) {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destinationVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RestaurantDetails") as! RestaurantDetailViewController
        destinationVC.resTransfer = res
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.showRestaurantViewControllerWith(self.restaurantArray[indexPath.row])
    }

    func searchBarSetup(){
        let searchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Name", "Rating", "Price"]

        searchBar.delegate = self
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    }
    //Mark: - Search Bar Delegate
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText:String){
        filterTableView(ind: searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex)
    }

    func filterTableView(ind: Int){
        switch ind {
        case selectedScope.name.rawValue:
            self.restaurantArray = self.restaurantArray.sorted(by: { (u1, u2) -> Bool in
                u1.name < u2.name
            })
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        case selectedScope.price.rawValue:
            self.restaurantArray = self.restaurantArray.sorted(by: { (u1, u2) -> Bool in
                u1.price.characters.count < u2.price.characters.count
            })
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        case selectedScope.rating.rawValue:
            self.restaurantArray = self.restaurantArray.sorted(by: { (u1, u2) -> Bool in
                u1.rating < u2.rating
            })
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        default:
            print("no type")
        }
    }






}
```

Comment: android sample hint. if(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()!=null)
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
    }

Comment: This seems related to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662340/firebase-only-load-data-once-and-close-using-completion-handler/41663160?noredirect=1#comment70524820_41663160), where I already said that you need to call `goOffline()` after processing the `.value` event.

Comment: I got the go offline to work now is there a way to close the firebase storage? I'm downloading a picture in my cell but I just realized that overtime I scroll up or down or even use the search bar it re downloads the picture